# Where is locate SQLite Database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my code given below:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DBNAME = "acc_db.db";

    private static final int VERSION = 4;


    private static DBHelper dbHelper = null;

    private static SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);
        // storing the object of this class to dbHelper
        dbHelper = this;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        DBTable.onCreate(database);
    }

    // Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
    // e.g. if you increase the database version

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        DBTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (dbHelper == null) {
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            openConnecion();
        }
        return dbHelper;
    }

    // will be called only once when singleton is created

    private static void openConnecion() {
        if (db == null) {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }


    public synchronized void closeConnecion() {
        if (dbHelper != null) {
            dbHelper.close();
            db.close();
            dbHelper = null;
            db = null;
        }
    }
}
```

where locate acc_db.db.
I will be search File Explorar=>data/data
but not found data sub folder under data folder.
[N.B] I am successfully CRUD operation using this data base.
Please help me any body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The databases are located in the private area of the app. Under a database folder. For example `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases`

Answer (score 0):

it is located in `/data/data/my.package.name/databases/`